# What happens to comments if I delete an answer?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers

I deleted an answer from Stack Overflow and all the comments of that answer is went under the question. The comments are inappropriate under that question. Is there a way to delete answer with all the comments? as I cannot delete other's comments under the question (they were about my answer before)

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. Do you have a link of the question?

Comment: No, comments do **not** just jump from a deleted answer to the question. They stay with the answer, which a 10k+ user could still see, as well as the associated comments.

Comment: When an answer is deleted then all the comments are deleted also. People with 10k rep will still be able to see these posts and will be able to confirm if the comments still exist alongside the answer. Not even moderators can move comments from one post to another (but they can convert an answer into a comment and assign it to any post).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments *stay with their post*. When you delete an answer, both the answer and the comments on that answer are just not shown to anyone with less than 10k reputation.

Users with 10k+ reputation can still view deleted answers and will see the comments there.

If you see comments on the question, they were re-posted there, they didn't get moved because you deleted the answer. If they are offensive or not constructive, you can flag those comments.